# Torque PBS: Specifying stdout file name to be the job id number

Tags: pbs, qsub, torque

By default, output from a submitted job to a Torque queue will be saved to a file named like `job_name.o658392`. What I want to do, using that example, is to name the output file `658392.job_name.log` instead.

I know I can specify the name of the output file by writing the line `#PBS -e filename` at the top of my script, and it is even possible to use variables such as `$PBS_JOBID` in the filename. 
The problem is that `$PBS_JOBID` is not just the number - instead it looks like `658392.some.very.long.host.name`.

I've tried using `${PBS_JOBID/.*}`, which should refer only to the numbers, but the problem is that I get an error doing this. It reads: `Failed to expand destination path in data staging: /path/to/output/${PBS_JOBID/.*}.log`

Do you know how to specify the output file name in a way that works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are an admin, you could get this to be just the numeric job id by setting

```
qmgr -c 'set server display_job_server_suffix = false'
```

Of course, if you change this setting you want to do it when you don't have jobs queued.

If you are a normal user-  I have not tested this - but I believe that if you add a variable to the job's environment you can use that variable in the job's output file. If you wanted to, you can make a variable called numeric_jobid and add that to the job's environment, and then you can use that in the job's output file. I believe you can have the following lines in job_script:

```
#PBS -j oe 
#PBS -o $numeric_jobid
```

Then

```
jobid=`qsub job_script`
numeric_id=`get just the numeric id from $jobid`
qalter $jobid -v numeric_id=$numeric_id
```

**EDIT**: you can save a step with this:

```
qalter -o $numeric_id.log $jobid
```

And I believe that would allow you to do it.

Comment: I added similar statements to my submit-script (I found out that `qalter` can set -o and -e directly). Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused about the "you can save a step" edit. It appears that `qalter -o $numeric_id.log $jobid` can be used in place of `qalter $jobid -v numeric_id=$numeric_id`, but both strategies require 3 lines of code. Am I missing something? Thanks.